# How do I grant unmanaged DLL with WRITE permission on files using fopen in ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, dllimport, unmanaged

I wrote an XML Web Service that run with an unmanaged dll which creates a file for writing.

But when my unmanaged dll tries to use `_wfopen` to **WRITE** something into an existing file, it causes a security issue: ACCESS DENIED!! And then `_wfopen` receives a `NULL` back.

I originally used `_wfopen` with `r+b` to access file. To test the permissions it had, 
I tried to change it to use `rb` (Read file only), then the file opened successfully. This means I can access the file with READ access.

I also found that directly accessing the file through C# code does not cause this problem.
(e.g. if I use `File.Create` etc.).

The OS I'm running is WinXP Professional SP3 with IIS 5.1. So there should **not** be directories or files permissions not set properly in such a system.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of **Code Fighting**, I came to a conclusion: **THIS MAY NOT BE A CODE PERMISSION ISSUE**.

So I tried to configure my web service in IIS.
I finally found that configuring the `ASP.NET` tab of the property page can solve this problem.

On the `ASP.NET` configuration page, I go to the `Application` tab and check `Impersonate` in `Identity Settings`, and input username/password with my computer login data.

After that, everything went well and the problem was solved.

I hope this helps for those who have the same problem as me.

Thanks for any advice!